# Sample files in the documents folder after installing the app

Tags: ios

is there a way that I can add sample files to the documents folder of an iOS-app before the app is actually started for the first time. For instance at install time.

For instance, I am writing a text editor and want to have a sample document, that the user can look at showing some of the features of the app. Could this sample be placed in some folder in Xcode and added to the documents folder automatically or do I have to add it from my code, the first time the app starts?

Comment: You can create this text document (on a background thread) in your document directory while application is launching and then read it as and when required. Or you can place this document in your bundle as well.

Comment: @RenoJones +1 for that suggestion. Since it's a sample text is going to be ready-only the best would be include in the bundle(just add the file with project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access files in sandbox. 
Add some resources files. You can load them and save them the way you want.

Comment: So I basically have to create the documents from resource files on launching.